# Реализация изменения фокуса div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, scss

Как реализовать перемещение между элементами с помощью кнопок вверх\вниз
На гифке продемонстрировано, то как реализовано в Bootstrap, тут с помощью кнопок вниз и вверх можно менять фокус на div`ах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: при появлении дива навешивается событие например `keypress`, если хочется конкретики можно глянуть как у них реализовано в исходниках если они доступны

Answer (score 0):

Реализовано это при помощи события `keydown` -> [подробнее](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent).

При этом все дивы собираются в массив `document.querySelectorAll('.droplist-div')`.

Затем, когда срабатывает событие 'keydown' происходит изменение класса на диве(например hover).
Как-то так.